# Error: While importing 'application', an ImportError was raised

Tags: python

```
from flask import flask
app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/'):
def index():
    return 'hrllo'
```

I keep getting

- Serving Flask app 'application.py' (lazy loading)
- Environment: development
- Debug mode: on
  Usage: flask run [OPTIONS]
  Try 'flask run --help' for help.

Error: While importing 'application', an ImportError was raised.

Comment: What's the name of the file you posted?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
from flask import Flask #changed "flask" to "Flask"
app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/')   #removed ":"
def index():
    return 'hello'

app.run() #added this line to run your application
```

Answer (score 1):

from flask import **Flask**, correction in your first line.
Remove the colon at the end of the line marking the `route`.

Also, you should do `app.run()` at the end of the code snippet.